# How to get multiple select query result in one line

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want oracle SQL query, that should join two tables and get all the group rows from second table in one row.

Example

```
field1    field2    field3
1          Test1    Ttest1
1          Test2    Ttest2
1          Test3    Ttest2
2          Test4    Ttest2 
2          Test5    T2est2
```

Should be

```
Field 1   field2                   field3
1         Test1,Test2,Test3        Ttest1,Ttest2
2         Test4,Test5              Ttest2
```

Comment: Oracle Version please!

Answer (score 2):

Use `LISTAGG` function.

```
SELECT field1,
       listagg(field2,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY field2) field2,
       listagg(field3,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY field3) field3
FROM   <table_name>
GROUP BY field1;
```

Use `DISTINC` in `WM_CONCAT` function to remove the duplicate from comma separated string.

```
SELECT field1,
       wm_concat(DISTINCT(field2)) field2,
       wm_concat(DISTINCT(field3)) field3
FROM   t
GROUP BY field1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WM_CONCAT of function to get result as you have mentioned.WM_CONCAT is used to concat the list of rows into one comma separated string .

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1,
   (SELECT WM_CONCAT(FIELD2) WHERE FIELD1 = T.FIELD1),
   (SELECT WM_CONCAT(FIELD3) WHERE FIELD1 = T.FIELD1) 
FROM TABLE T;
```

But this solution will be oracle specific.

Comment: Vijay, this will concat but `filed1` needs to be grouped for OPs requirement

Comment: @OracleUser Thanks for identifying, I have updated the answer.